# Get Texture2D of gameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem getting the texture2D of my gameobject.

my gameobject has a sprite renderer that contains a Texture type of advance with read/write enabled to checked.

here is my code:

```
SpriteRenderer go;
void Start () {

    go = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();

}

void Update () {
    print (go.material.mainTexture.height);
}
```

I just want to display the height, I feel once I get this I can do whatever I want with every pixel of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of taking the texture from the material, remember that it is a SpriteRenderer component, therefore it has a Sprite on it, not a regular Texture, so try taking the Texture2D directly from the sprite.

```
print(go.sprite.texture.height);
```

also if this does not work for you, tell us what are you getting so it will be easier to understand the problem.

Comment: Right I got the right output, the problem is apparently I can't change the alpha of my sprite image on a particular pixel

Comment: @VonnCC check out the documentation about SetPixel: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixel.html

Just saw your edit, glad you figured it out. good luck :)